# How to get information of foreign key when selected to another table when selected specific key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have three tables, one is mandal, village and Property, in the property table i have linked mandal and village with foreign key, now when i select mandal, only that particular village results should have to shown in property form in django admin. I have also linked mandal with village.

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Mandal(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        db_column="Mandal_id",
        verbose_name="Mandal Id",
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        db_column="Mandal_Name",
        verbose_name="Mandal Name",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text="Enter Mandal names only",
        default=None,
    )
    class Meta:
        db_table = "Mandal"
        verbose_name_plural = "Mandal"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Village(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        db_column="Village_id",
        verbose_name="Village Id",
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        db_column="Village_Name",
        verbose_name="Village Name",
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text="Enter village names only",
        default=None,
    )
    mandal_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Mandal,
        db_column="Mandal_id",
        verbose_name="Mandal Name",
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Village"
        verbose_name_plural="Village"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Properties(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        db_column="Property_id",
        verbose_name="Property Id"
    )
    created_on = models.DateField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=False,
        default=timezone.now(),
    )
    area = models.BigIntegerField(
        default=0,
        db_column="Property_Area",
        verbose_name="Property Area",
        help_text="Please enter area in square feet",
        validators=[],
    )
    mandal_location = models.ForeignKey(
        Mandal,
        db_column="Mandal_id",
        verbose_name="Mandal Name",
        default=None,
    )
    village_location = models.ForeignKey(
        Village,
        db_column="Village_id",
        verbose_name="Village Name",
        default=None,
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        default=None,
        db_column="Property_description",
        verbose_name="Property Description",
    )
    features = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        db_column="Property_Features",
        verbose_name="Property Features",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Add Property Fetures",
        max_length=1000,
    )
    additional_features = models.CharField(
        default=None,
        db_column="Property_Additional_Features",
        verbose_name="Additional Features",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Add Property Fetures",
        max_length=1000
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Properties"
        verbose_name_plural = "Property"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Pr-{i}".format(i=self.id)

#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from whiteindia.models import Mandal,Village,Properties

class MandalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','name']

    class Meta:
        model = Mandal

class VillageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','name','mandal_id']
    list_filter = ['mandal_id']

    class Meta:
        model = Village

class PropertiesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'area','village_location','mandal_location']

    class Meta:
        model = Properties

admin.site.register(Mandal,MandalAdmin)
admin.site.register(Village,VillageAdmin)
admin.site.register(Properties,PropertiesAdmin)
```

So how to get villages list to a specific mandal in the property in admin when we enter admin/property in browser window

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you are wanting to display your data but have you looked at inlineModelAdmin.

> The admin interface has the ability to edit models on the same page as a parent model. These are called inlines.

I use this to edit a record in my admin pages which also displays any child records from another table that can also be edited. In your case you might be able to use it to click a property to edit it and, on the edit page underneath the property, it could show all the Mandals or villages that relate to it.  If you want to link 3 tables you can do so using the 'through' option. Check out the docs at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin

Comment: In the model - property, if i select mandal, i should get list of villages associated with the specific mandal.

Comment: Your property list is showing a mandal location through the foreign key.  If you are wanting to click on this key and then show a separate list of villages, you will need to capture the primary key of the record and pass it to another view.  This may involve having to overwrite or subclass some of the admin classes.  You should check out the docs on customising the admin section in order to do this.  As an alternative you may be able use inlines to show a list of madals for a property and possibly a list of villages of a mandal using the 'through' option. Depends how you want your app to look.